# Display count of values in PHP array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I can not seem to come over this easy problem.

I have the following code, where I select the column "status" from a table. There's three different values of "status", 0, 1 and 3.

I would like to count how many 0's there are, 1's and 2's, so that I can display them via `<?php echo $accepted; ?>` etc.

```
<?php 

    $sql = "SELECT status FROM applications";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM);
    $array = array_count_values($row);
    $pending = $array[0];
    $accepted = $array[1];
    $denied = $array[2];


?>
```

MYSQL_NUM changed to MYSQLI_NUM accordingly to comment, thank you.

Comment: Did you `print_r($array)`? What did you see?

Comment: I got this: Array ( [2] => 1 ) 

The sql table contains 4 rows, 2 with status=2, 2 with status=1.

Comment: for one thing `MYSQL_NUM` should read as `MYSQLI_NUM`

Comment: now you went and used code from an answer below but didn't include *"The code I used given in an answer did not work...."*. What you should have done was, left the question intact and place a comment under the answer. Now that person could get downvoted because of that. Edit: as you seem to have done now. IMHO, you should have left your code the way it was.

Comment: Sorry, should I put that in the question?

Comment: And second - you don't understand how results are returned from mysql.

Comment: I've rolled the question back.

Comment: btw, you only selected one column in your select and again... `MYSQL_NUM` should read as `MYSQLI_NUM` with the added `I`.

Comment: I only need the "status" column to see how many pending, accepted and denied applications there are?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple way is get these count using SQL

```
  $sql = "SELECT `status`, COUNT(*) as cnt FROM applications GROUP BY `status`";
```

you have an array of so you should

```
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
 {
   echo "status = " . $array['status'] . ' = ' . $array['cnt'] .'<br />';
 }
```

Comment: You should accept this answer it's the correct way to go but honestly you need to better you code in small applications this is fine but if you r looking to scale up you will regret this sorta code later

Comment: @JoséphFlames   your comment if for me or for the OP  ... and if you can please explain better  .. ..

Comment: I've updated the questions with my new code, The array result is now: Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 ) , how comes?

Comment: It was for Adam and I mean for one he is using sql which is depreciated and secondly he needs to use prepared statementz

Comment: OP is using mysqli_ and you have `mysql_fetch_array` and `MYSQL_ASSOC` both missing `I`'s Edit: where Martin missed one. Edit: there we go ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii-   . thanks  .. the asnwer  sis already edit by martin .. thanks to Martin too.

Comment: Is this the most efficient way?

Comment: I think yes .. because you are using a full scan select and the performance are pratically the same with the group by .. (also for relative big tables ) .. but with a sigle query you have the full result without others server calculation